# How many Garbage collector instances are created in ASP.Net when multiple applications are running on single OS?

Tags: asp.net, memory-management, garbage-collection, operating-system, heap-memory

Is there a single GC for an OS for Asp.Net Or there is single per CLR/Process running?

And if its not single for an OS then how individual GCs decide whether to ask more memory from OS or to throw OutOfMemory exception (Don't they need to have idea about overall state of OS memory)?

Answer (score 0):

1.**There is a per CLR/Process GC not in OS lvl.**

Basically Garbage Collector in.Net has two modes **Workstation** and **Server**.

**Workstation** modes assumes thath other applications are running on the machine and does not hog the cpu(**which means that other process could use cpu for their own  GC collection**),allow other applications /process uses cpu for **THEIR OWN** GC process.

**Server** mode assumes that there is no other  application running on the server and it assumes that all cpu on the machine are available to assist with completing GC.This GC mode caused managed heap to be splited in a couple of sections  on per CPU.And as you can guess each cpu is responsible for each section of managed heap.

By default all applications in .Net(including ASP.NET) running on the Workstation mod but we can enable through config file Server mod.Like this

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
   <gcServer enabled = "true"/>
  </runtime>
 </configuration>
```

2. OutOfMemory exception will be thrown when GC will go throug all **zero** based generations objects and figured out that there is not enough memeory. And start making collection through all generations **one and two**. If in that case it determines that there is again not enoguh memory will be thrown OutOfMemoryException.